# Difference between instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and initWithNibName?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

What is the difference between **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier** and **initWithNibName**, other than former is from storyboard and later is not?

```
UIStoryboard *signupStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SignupStory" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SignupLoginViewController *signUpVC = [signupStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignupVC"];
```

and

```
SignupLoginViewController *signUpVC = [[SignupLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignupLoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've created your UI using storyboards, you'll want to call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. Here, the identifier is not part of the view controller itself but is only used by the storyboard to locate the view controller. The storyboard will handle initialization and eventually call `initWithCoder`, which is why you need to override this when creating subclassed view controllers.

On the other hand, if your UI resides in a pure .xib file - developers generally use `initWithNibName`. It does, technically, break encapsulation and there are other ways to do it, but you'll see this used most often as it's the designated initializer for the class.

Comment: As a side note. `[[SomeViewController alloc] init];` will search for a nib called `SomeViewController.xib` and load from there if it exists.

Comment: Thanks @DreamingInBinary
Can you please explain that "break encapsulation" part.

Comment: @SanjayPathak Sure - in short NIB is an implementation detail that should only concern the view controller itself and not the outside caller. It's a better design pattern to override init and provide this internal detail there. Also, please accept this answer if it answered your question.